# Wrongfully received consecutive days badge for the third time

Tags: bug, badges

For the third time now, I've received a consecutive days badge when I know for a fact that I haven't earned it. The first time was reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285509/300788) and the second time [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288220/300788).

I just looked at my achievements menu, and saw this:

[image: Achievements screenshot]

While I love PPGC, I know I haven't visited it for a month straight, let alone 100 days. I've been busy with work and a Neural Net project, so I haven't been checking it frequently. I think I checked it last a few days ago, and before that a week or two prior.

Things to note:

- I don't have any scripts, browser or otherwise that check or even have access to SE.
- My SE account is tied to Google, which has two-step verification in place, and monthly activity reports. My account is spotless. This isn't a case of someone logging in to my account (and checking PPCG!?).
- Again, I know for a fact that I haven't even visited the site daily for at least a month, if not more.
- I predominantly use the Android app. PPCG is listed as one of my favorite sites in the left menu.

While I'd like to keep the badge(s), I thought I'd post another report since the first 2 didn't have any kind of resolution.

Comment: Continuing to post new reports each time it happens really doesn't help us out any more than having the one report.

Comment: @animuson Thought it might help. But ok, I won't post if it happens again.

Comment: @animuson So how to let still-occurring old bugs get some attention?